# textreuse::TextReuseCorpus generates error when passing in a variable

Tags: r

Trying to use the **textreuse** library to implement the minhash algorithm and when I execute this code I get a valid result.

```
library(janeaustenr)
library(dplyr)
library(textreuse)
library(tibble)
library(tokenizers)
library(assertthat)
custom_tokenize_ngrams <- function(string, lowercase = TRUE, n = 3) {
  assertthat::assert_that(length(string) == 1)
  tokenizers::tokenize_ngrams(x = string, lowercase = lowercase, n = n) |> unlist()
}

  janeaustenr::austen_books() |>
  dplyr::mutate(i_row = dplyr::row_number()) |> 
  dplyr::select(i_row, text) |>
  dplyr::mutate_all(as.character) |>
  dplyr::filter(nchar(text)>50 & nchar(text)<1000) |>
  utils::head(500) |>
  tibble::deframe() |>
  {\(.) 
    textreuse::TextReuseCorpus(
      text = ., 
      tokenizer = custom_tokenize_ngrams, 
      minhash_func = textreuse::minhash_generator(n = 60, seed = 123456) , 
      keep_tokens = TRUE,
      progress = TRUE, 
      n = 2L
    ) 
    }()
```

But if I try to pass **n** to **TextReuseCorpus** as a variable I get an error, this virtually identical code generates an error.

```
library(janeaustenr)
library(dplyr)
library(textreuse)
library(tibble)
library(tokenizers)
library(assertthat)
custom_tokenize_ngrams <- function(string, lowercase = TRUE, n = 3) {
  assertthat::assert_that(length(string) == 1)
  tokenizers::tokenize_ngrams(x = string, lowercase = lowercase, n = n) |> unlist()
}


nx = 2L

  janeaustenr::austen_books() |>
  dplyr::mutate(i_row = dplyr::row_number()) |> 
  dplyr::select(i_row, text) |>
  dplyr::mutate_all(as.character) |>
  dplyr::filter(nchar(text)>50 & nchar(text)<1000) |>
  utils::head(500) |>
  tibble::deframe() |>
  {\(.) 
    textreuse::TextReuseCorpus(
      text = ., 
      tokenizer = custom_tokenize_ngrams, 
      minhash_func = textreuse::minhash_generator(n = 60, seed = 123456) , 
      keep_tokens = TRUE,
      progress = TRUE, 
      n = nx
    ) 
    }()
```

ERROR

```
Error in n_call + 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I am really not sure why this is happening, or how I can fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is seems that error was [reported back in 2017](https://github.com/ropensci/textreuse/pull/80) but it doesn't look like it was actually fixed because the [problem code is still there](https://github.com/ropensci/textreuse/blob/0f453d603816fcd8521303dee8ac42b35537b5b9/R/TextReuseTextDocument.R#L87). It doesn't look like the `textreuse` package has been updated in 2 years so I'm not sure if that will be fixed properly.

You can write a wrapper around the function to force evaulation of that parameter.

```
myTextReuseCorpus <- function(..., n=3){
  mc <- match.call()
  if (!is.null(mc$n)) {
    mc$n <- eval.parent(mc$n)
  }
  mc[[1]] <- quote(TextReuseCorpus)
  eval.parent(mc)
}
```

and then use that

```
janeaustenr::austen_books() |>
  dplyr::mutate(i_row = dplyr::row_number()) |> 
  dplyr::select(i_row, text) |>
  dplyr::mutate_all(as.character) |>
  dplyr::filter(nchar(text)>50 & nchar(text)<1000) |>
  utils::head(500) |>
  tibble::deframe() |>
  {\(.) 
    myTextReuseCorpus(
      text = ., 
      tokenizer = custom_tokenize_ngrams, 
      minhash_func = textreuse::minhash_generator(n = 60, seed = 123456) , 
      keep_tokens = TRUE,
      progress = TRUE,
      n = nx
    ) 
  }()
```